# jquery toggle only first target

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I created a toggle for an image display an about me section below it. I used targets to trigger the appropriate section. The code works fine on http://codepen.io/CookieFresh89/pen/OPOvXK.

However when I put this on my [Wordpress website](http://sogomarketingagency.com/test-2/), all of the images target the first id="div1".

HTML

```
<img class="showSingle" target="1" src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/about-me-holder.jpg">

<img class="showSingle" target="2" src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/about-me-holder.jpg">

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv bio">Lorum Ipsum1 <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></div></div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv bio">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
```

CSS

```
.targetDiv {
    display: none
}

.bio {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}
```

jquery

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index(),
            newTarget = jQuery('.targetDiv').eq(index).slideDown();
        $(".close").show("fast");
        jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp();
    });
  $(".bio").click(function(){
      $(".hide").hide("fast");
      $(this).toggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Comment: from what I can see.. you're using a combination of `$` and `jQuery` to represent a jQuery statement.. try replacing all `$` with `jQuery` in your wordpress implementation.

Comment: of course, the assumption here is that you're using WP jQuery plugin or something similiar.. and not having conflicts: https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/wp-jquery-plus

Comment: by the way.. what's the relevance of the target attribute?.. you could make it `data-target` and jquery will parse it into the data object.. `newTarget = jQuery(this).data('target')`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try that when I get home. The jquery above was something I found on stack overflow. I just modified it. Is the code I have improper compared to what you suggested?

Comment: @bobdye is correct, `$.index` is "The DOM element or first element within the jQuery object to look for.".. in your wordpress implementation, each of your images are the first DOM element, because they are wrapped in `p`.. which is not the case in your codepen implementation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement:

```
var index = $(this).index(),
```

the $(this) only has one element, so index is always 1.

Use:

```
var index = $('.showSingle').index(this),
```

instead. If you look at the jQuery .index() documentation at http://api.jquery.com/index/, this looks in the collection $('.showSingle') to find the one matching the DOM element given by "this".

---

### Sample Code Snippet

```js
$.noConflict(); // this is not a necessary line in your wordpress implemention

    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function () {
            var index = jQuery('.showSingle').index(this),
                newTarget = jQuery('.targetDiv').eq(index).slideDown();
            jQuery(".close").show("fast");
            jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp();
        });
      jQuery(".bio").click(function(){
          jQuery(".hide").hide("fast");
          jQuery(this).toggle("fast");
      });
    });
```

```css
.targetDiv {
    display: none
}

.bio {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}

.bio:before,
.bio:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 15px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 135px;
}

.bio:before {
  border-color: grey transparent;
  top: -16px;
}

.bio:after {
  border-color: #f6f6f6 transparent;
  top: -14px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <img class="showSingle" target="1" src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/about-me-holder.jpg">    
  <img class="showSingle" target="2" src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/about-me-holder.jpg">

    <div id="div1" class="targetDiv bio">Lorum Ipsum1 <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></div></div>
    <div id="div2" class="targetDiv bio">Lorum Ipsum2 <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></div></div>
```

Comment: you are correct.. Can you add a reference to $.index: http://api.jquery.com/index/, and cite "The DOM element or first element within the jQuery object to look for." and the wordpress DOM difference being the 'culprit'

Answer (score 1):

Here is the data attribute alternative I was referring to in comments.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.showSingle').click(function () {
        var newTarget = $('.targetDiv').eq($(this).data('target')).slideDown();
        // $.eq is 0 based array; data-target
        $(".close").show("fast");
        $('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp();
    });
  $(".bio").click(function(){
      $(".hide").hide("fast");
      $(this).toggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {
    display: none
}

.bio {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}

.bio:before,
.bio:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 15px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 135px;
}

.bio:before {
  border-color: grey transparent;
  top: -16px;
}

.bio:after {
  border-color: #f6f6f6 transparent;
  top: -14px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="showSingle" data-target="0" src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/about-me-holder.jpg">

<img class="showSingle" data-target="1" src="http://sogomarketingagency.com/wp-content/uploads/about-me-holder.jpg">

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv bio">Lorum Ipsum1 
    <div class="close">
    <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv bio">Lorum Ipsum2
    <div class="close">
    <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```